# Vuetify v-carousel with vuex async computed images not working properly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuetify.js

I try to load images over `firestore` in `Vuex` and loop with `v-for` over the `computed` property in the component. The images are there but there first image of the slide is blank. If i start the carousel the correct second image shows up and from there it works normal.

My question is why is the first `v-carousel-item` blank? and second why does it not start?

Here is my code for the component:

```
<template>
  <v-container app fluid>

    <p>home</p>
    <v-carousel>
      <v-carousel-item
        cycle
        v-for="(item,i) in carouselImages"
        :key="i"
        :src="item.url"       
      >
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
const { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } = createNamespacedHelpers('carousel')

export default {
  name: 'app',

  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'getCarouselImages'
    ])
  },
  computed : {
    ...mapGetters({
      carouselImages: 'loadedCarouselImages'
    })
  },

  created(){
    console.log("created");
    this.getCarouselImages();

  }
}
```

here is my vuex store module code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import firestore from '../../firebase/firestore'

Vue.use(Vuex)


const state = {
  carouselImages: []
}

const mutations = {
  setImages(state, payload){
    state.carouselImages.push(payload);
  }
}

const actions = {
  getCarouselImages: ({ commit }) => {
    firestore.collection("Carousel").get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(image => {
          commit('setImages',image.data());
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}

const getters = {
  loadedCarouselImages: state => {
    return state.carouselImages.sort((imageA, imageB)=>{
      return imageA.pos < imageB.pos
    })
  }
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

I try to research a similar problem but i did not found something.
I maybe have to start the carousel manually? Or why does it not start even the state changes correctly in the `created` hook. And also everything works fine the moment i click it manually.

Thank you guys for your help.

Kind regards

Dany

### Update

I also tried the same with the `VueFire` Libary and got the same behaviour.
Here the code:

```
<template>
  <v-carousel cycle>
    <v-carousel-item
      v-for="(item,i) in items"
      :key="i"
      :src="item.url"
      >
    </v-carousel-item>
  </v-carousel>

</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../firebase/firestore";


export default {
  name: 'Carousel',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data(){
    return{
      items: []
    }
  },
  firestore(){
    return{
      items: db.collection('Carousel')
    }
    console.log(this.items);
  },
  created(){
    console.log(this.items);
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix the whole problem, but the `cycle` prop [goes on the v-carousel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels#api), not the v-carousel-item. Ala `<v-carousel cycle>`

Comment: Tried that too did not fix the problem. Meanwhile i did it with the VueFire and firestore() implementation and it shows the same behavour.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I did wrap the `v-carousel` in a `v-layout` and added a `v-if` with a new computed value loading.

This way it waits until its true and than shows it. The Carousel behaviour is now normal. I am new here so if there is a way to update it correct please tell me.

Component:

```
<template>
  <v-layout v-if="!loading">
    <v-carousel cycle>
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="(item,i) in carouselImages"
        :key="i"
        v-bind:src="item.url"
        >
      </v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import { db } from "../firebase/firestore";
  import { createNamespacedHelpers } from 'vuex'
  const { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } = createNamespacedHelpers('carousel')

  export default {
    name: 'Carousel',

    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'getCarouselImages'
      ])
    },
    computed : {
      ...mapGetters({
        carouselImages: 'loadedCarouselImages',
        loading: 'loading'
      })
    },
    created(){
      this.getCarouselImages();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { db } from "../../firebase/firestore";

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
  loading: true,
  carouselImages: []
}

const mutations = {
  setImages(state, payload){
    state.carouselImages.push(payload);
  },
  setLoading (state, payload) {
    state.loading = payload
  }
}

const actions = {
  getCarouselImages: ({ commit }) => {
    commit('setLoading', true);
    db.collection("Carousel").get()
      .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(image => {
          commit('setImages',image.data());
          commit('setLoading', false);
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }
}

const getters = {
  loadedCarouselImages: state => {
    return state.carouselImages.sort((imageA, imageB)=>{
      return imageA.pos < imageB.pos
    })
  },
  loading: state => {
    return state.loading
  },
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue with pulling the url from Firestore and displaying the images in the carousel. I'm loading the images in the component itself rather than the store, but I used v-model to not load the images until after the querySnapshot is complete. It starts off on the second image and there is a little delay but it starts automatically and seems to work okay.